# How to make a single word look as some code?

Tags: fonts, code

I would like to be able to make a single word in a text look like a coded word. Is there any command such as `\code{...}` which allows me to do so?

(basically, I want to produce something like above for the "\code{...}" part)

Comment: Do you want it to change the background to grey too?

Comment: @N.N : it could have been even better yeah, but it's not extremely important.

Comment: The answer is `texttt{}` how that is an unhuman command. How is anyone suppose to remember this? If you figure out what the ttt's stand for please tell me!

Comment: @CharlieParker I'm pretty sure `texttt` stands for text [teletype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleprinter). Similarly there are for example `\textrm`, where rm stands for roman, and `\textsf` where sf stands for serif.

Answer (score 211, accepted):

Normally a monospaced font is used for this. This is accomplished with `\texttt{...}`. If you want to use code, you can use `\def\code#1{\texttt{#1}}`. From that point on you can write `\code{...}` to get monospaced output.

Comment: Yes, that's the way to go. Put it semantically correct (by calling it `code`) and use `texttt` inside this until you come across a better formatting.

Comment: I'd prefer `\newcommand{\code}[1]{\texttt{#1}}` as you're dealing with LaTeX. Even better `\newcommand{\code}{\texttt}`, but this is quite advanced.

Comment: @egreg I'm not so sure about the last approach (yes, I know why you're doing it, but from an interface POV I prefer macros where the arguments required are clear).

Comment: @JosephWright That's why I wrote that it's advanced. :)

Comment: I would also wrap a `\mbox` around the `\texttt`, to avoid the word being hyphenated if it happens to fall near the end of a line.

Comment: I would agree that `\newcommand` is slightly better. @KarlOveHufthammer: Regarding the `\mbox` I would disagree. It is perfectly possible to have long function names, possibly with arguments. You would surely want those to be wrapped.

Comment: @wh1t3 Would you really want them hyphenated? That could become very confusing for the reader, especially for languages that use commands that *can* contain hyphens. For function names with arguments, I would define a separate command that handles this in a proper way, using penalties to get the optimal wrapping (e.g., never break the function name, but make is possible (but bad) to break at the comma between arguments).

Comment: @KarlOveHufthammer: I don't want them hyphenated, but I don't want them mboxed either. Perhaps having an mbox around them to spot problems (over/underful hboxes) and then being able to deal with these issues is acceptable though.

Comment: @wh1t3 You might also consider using the `seqsplit` package to allow breaking the ‘word’ everywhere, but without a hyphen. The result may be very ugly, though, with for example one letter before or after the break.

Comment: @egreg: Reduce that to `\let\code=\texttt` altogether.

Comment: @KarlOveHufthammer: normally tt-fonts set `\hyphenchar \font\m@ne` and so disable hyphenation anyway.

Comment: `\texttt{}` what sort of command is that! How is anyone suppose to remember that? What does it stand for? Why so many t's `tt`?

Comment: @CharlieParker `\texttt{}` is named with the same logic as `\textbf{}`. That is, '\text' followed by the style abbreviated. The `bf` is short for bold face and `tt` is short for teletype which is the traditional name for monospaced fonts.

Comment: @egreg 11 years later, but I can see you even have an answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49445/191627) recommending something like `\newcommand{\code}{\texttt}`, but don't detail why you call it advanced. Are there gotchas to watch out for / any documentation that discusses the difference?

Comment: @Kraigolas TeX does macro expansion. If you have `\newcommand{\code}[1]{\texttt{#1}}` when `\code` is expanded it reads its argument and passes it to `\texttt` which has to read it again. With `\newcommand{\code}{\texttt}` you don't read the argument twice. The overhead is negiligible, with modern machines. I'd not go with `\let\code=\texttt` for several reasons.

Answer (score 42):

If you want a single word to look like a coded word and also to have a light-gray background as in StackExchange you can predefine a color `\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95}` and then define a new command: `\newcommand{\code}[1]{\colorbox{light-gray}{\texttt{#1}}}`.

From this point on you can use `\code{word}` to get mono-spaced words with gray background.

Of course for this to work you will need to load the `xcolor` package before `\definecolor`.

A full example would look like this:

```latex
% Better inline directory listings
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95}
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\colorbox{light-gray}{\texttt{#1}}}
```

Comment: Awesome, that's what I was looking for. Thanks :D

Comment: This is what the people want!

Comment: Hi. I've tried to do this in a document, but my document won't compile unless I surround the word like \code{$word$}, and then it puts everything in math font. When I don't it says "! Missing $ inserted.". Any ideas?

Comment: @lafemmecosmique Did your 'word' contain underscores?

Comment: Yes it did. I had to escape character them out like \code{word\_1}

Comment: I wish I could manually award this answer a bounty

Comment: To be even more StackExchange like, would it be possible to use ticks ``` instead of `code{...}` to identify what should be styled as code?

Comment: Awesome. I just coded this exact solution myself (color and all) before searching for community solutions. Great minds think alike!

Answer (score 28):

I can't believe nobody mentioned the `listings` package. It provides a command called `\lstinline{your_code}` which can even highlight keywords for you.

See also this question: [Should I use \lstinline for the language keywords embedded in text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205362/should-i-use-lstinline-for-the-language-keywords-embedded-in-text)

Comment: Syntax: `\lstinline[⟨key=value list⟩]⟨character⟩⟨source code⟩⟨same character⟩` Also, some engines support a wider working range of working <character> delimiters. For exampe, I found `¿` to work with xelatex and not with pdflatex.

Comment: This should be the answer. No hands-on formatting where it can be avoided in LaTeX.

Comment: This is the best answer and it could be mixed with others `\newcommand{\code}[1]{\lstinline{#1}}`

Answer (score 17):

`\verb|code|` or `\verb#code#` also works. It creates characters in monospace, although its primary utility to enter commands that the compiler wont confuse as tex commands.

Comment: Why does `\verb` use `|` or `#` to start and end code rather than the usual `{` and `}`?

Comment: @user3728501 what if I wanted to give an example LaTeX command using verbatim? I'd need different delimiters to indicate when to start/stop the verbatim text (since the `{` and `}` would need to be rendered as verbatim text).

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend my package [`ffcode`](https://ctan.org/pkg/ffcode), which makes it as simple as this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ffcode}
\begin{document}
The function \ff{foo} can be used in a loop:
\begin{ffcode}
while (true) {
  foo(i++);
}
\end{ffcode}
\end{document}
```

The package uses [`minted`](https://ctan.org/pkg/minted) for code blocks and [`tcolorbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) for individual words.