# Aliasing a command to another

Tags: macros, memoir

I have the command `\DoubleSpacing` within the caption of many of my figures throughout my document. This command is provided by `memoir.`

```
...
\caption[]{\DoubleSpacing Here is a figure caption}
...
```

I would like to replace this command by some other command, say `aux_command` that I can alias to `\DoubleSpacing` or to a dummy command that does nothing (literally), at will, and in one single place. This would allow me to quickly turn on and off DoubleSpacing in the caption of my figures. How can I do that?

Comment: Don't double space your documents, if you're not required to by (absurd) rules. Never double space captions, even if the (absurd) rules seem to require it.

Comment: Thanks @egreg. Unfortuantely I am required to do this in the first drafts, which is why I know I will have to turn it off later.

Comment: `\def\DoubleSpecing{}` will change the command to do nothing.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

While it might be possible to patch the `\@makecaption` inner command of `memoir`, the best thing to do is to have

```
\newcommand{\CaptionDS}{\DoubleSpacing}
%\newcommand{\CaptionDS}{}
```

and use `\CaptionDS` in captions. When doing the final version, you simply switch the comments (or remove `\CaptionDS` altogether, which will be easier with a "search and replace").

Comment: I think I will accept this question because it's the one that directly answers the question, although I should point out Alan's answer also fit perfectly the specifics of my problem.

Answer (score 19):

Instead of aliasing the `\DoubleSpacing` command and using it inside every caption, you should set up your caption properly using `memoir`'s hooks for caption style:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\captionstyle{\DoubleSpacing}
\begin{document}
\chapter{}
\begin{figure}
\caption{This is a caption that will be double spaced as you require. It will have a caption that is doublespaced as you require.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This way you don't have to do any search and replace, and you can change the caption setup once in the preamble.