# Should I use \lstinline for the language keywords embedded in text?

Tags: listings

When writing about programming languages, there are examples to format as listings. That works fine and produces beautiful results. Sometimes I want to mention the keywords used in the listing further in the text, like that `declare` that I put in bold italic.

I tried `\lstinline` but it seems to simply print its argument verbatim without applying the same text formatting as in the listing. Is there any other mechanism to typeset the keywords or short snippets within regular text, while obeying the same language formatting as specified in `\lstset`?

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\lstset{frameround=fttt,language=SQL,numbers=left,breaklines=true}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={SQL},label={lst:sql}]
declare @t table(
  id int
)
\end{lstlisting}

The above Listing \ref{lst:sql} demonstrates how to use \textbf{\textit{declare}} statement to create a table variable.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes, I would recommend you use `\lstinline` so that the same style is applied:

[image]

Note that even though it *appears* the formatting is the same, if you look carefully you will notice that the spacing of the keywords in the `\lstinline` is slightly different than the `listings`.

The reason for that is that the default for `\lstinline` as per the documentation is that `\lstinline`

> works like `\verb` but respects the active language and style. These listings use flexible columns unless requested differently in the optional argument

So, you need to change the column specification with the optional parameter:

```
\lstinline[columns=fixed]{declare}
```

or use `\lstMakeShortInline[columns=fixed]|` to define a special char (in this case the vertical unix pipe) and simply use `|declare|`:

[image]

---

If you don't want to specify the `\basicstyle` you get:

[image]

---

### Summary:

- `[columns=fixed]` needs to be applied to the `\lstinline`.

---

### Code: Specify `\basicstyle`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{
    frameround=fttt,
    language=SQL,
    numbers=left,
    breaklines=true,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries, 
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\color{red},
    numberstyle=\color{black}
    }
\lstMakeShortInline[columns=fixed]|

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={SQL},label={lst:sql}]
declare @t table(
  id int
)
\end{lstlisting}

The above Listing \ref{lst:sql} demonstrates how to use |declare| statement to create a |table| variable.

\end{document}
```

---

### Code: Without `\basicstyle`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\lstset{frameround=fttt,language=SQL,numbers=left,breaklines=true}

\lstMakeShortInline[columns=fixed]|


\begin{lstlisting}[caption={SQL},label={lst:sql}]
declare @t table(
  id int
)
\end{lstlisting}

\noindent Using \verb+\lstinlne+:\par
The above Listing \ref{lst:sql} demonstrates how to use \lstinline[columns=fixed]{declare} statement to create a \lstinline{table} variable.

\noindent Using \verb+|+:\par
The above Listing \ref{lst:sql} demonstrates how to use |declare| statement to create a \lstinline{table} variable.


\end{document}
```

Comment: Or define a shorthand for it with `\lstMakeShortInline`.

Comment: @Jubobs It is interesting that you used a different format of `\lstinline` than I saw in the listings manual. They said on p.4 that it should be used as follows: ``\lstinline!var i:integer;!'` What am I missing?

Comment: @ajeh Did you mean to address that last comment to Peter Grill instead of to me?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: For some reason that syntax does not seem to work for me. When I added 3 more parameters to `\lstset` they broke the listings. I am now getting undefined control sequence on each of them. When I go back to my setup it works. Without your 3 new parameters the inline listings render in the same regular text font.

Comment: I missed that you included `xcolor` package. That's why the colors were killing me. Now I see that the fonts of the listings are completely different. So it seems that w/o changing the listing `basicstyle` font the inline listings will not render in the same font and style as the block listings with this approach. Am I missing anything else?

Comment: @ajeh: Sorry, I should have pointed out that I added `xcolor` so that it was easier to see that the inline listings and the environment maintained consistent formatting.  Yes, I believe that if you don't set `\basicstyle` then the text which are not keywords will take on the font of the surrounding text. Keywords are different in that the `language=SQL` must be defining `keywordstyle=\bfseries`. But that language file is not defining a `\basicstyle`.

Comment: How can I preserve the default block listing style, yet define `basicstyle` for the inline listings to work? Perhaps should I try a different language?

Comment: @ajeh: I think that should be a separate question -- That way it is likely to be help to others as it'll be easier to find.

Comment: No, it is still the same original question - how to format the inline comments same as the block comments.

Comment: @ajeh: Sorry I misunderstood. So, are you saying that prefer to _not_ specify `\basicstyle` _and_ have the same output with `listings` enviroment and `lstinline`?

Comment: @ajeh: Please see updated solution.

Comment: Even though I do not understand how that works, it is interesting again. Perhaps the difficulty a non-English speaker such as myself is having reading an English manual written by a German speaker is understandable, maybe not, but I fail to make a connection between fixed column format as described by Heinz and Hoffmann on p. 21 and how it fixed basic style in your example.

Comment: @ajeh: Yeah TeX can be confusing at times. I had to reread the documentation several times to get it, so don't feel bad. Also, I noticed a slight error in my previous version and have corrected it. You _must_ specify `[columns=fixed]` for `\lstinline` in either case.

Comment: @PeterGrill That worked for the most part, but still produced a nasty side effect: an extra blank space at the beginning of the line onto which the inline listing wraps. Virtually every inline listing that wraps onto the next line starts 1 blank space after the beginning of that line now.

Comment: @ajeh: I can't seem to duplicate it. I'd recommend you post a new question.