# How to convert _ to \_

Tags: macros, symbols

In [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36030/how-to-make-a-single-word-look-as-some-code), answers suggested using `\newcommand{\code}[1]{\texttt{#1}}` to type in a stylized code font. This works rather nicely, however, I am trying to write about code in a website, where the format/convention for naming functions is to have them be `multiple_words_long_with_underscores_representing_spaces`. However, I'm rather lazy, and would rather not have to repeatedly preface each underscore with a backslash. I realize I could use find-replace-methods, but is there a latex method to add this into my `\newcommand{\code}[1]{\texttt{#1}}` shortcut?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using [`listings`](//ctan.org/pkg/listings)' `\lstinline` (experimental):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  basicstyle = \ttfamily
}
\let\code\lstinline

\begin{document}

Some regular text.
Some \code{code} inline.
Then some \code{multiple_words} code word.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not just `\detokenize`?

Comment: @daleif: As in [Underscores in words (text)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139980/5764)? ;) Code is typically formatted using `listings`; that's my motivation for using it.

Comment: @daleif without any spaces in the name, `\detokenize` will not linebreak.  That may or may not be an issue for the OP.

Comment: @StevenBSegletes will listings break lines from inline?

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\ustexttt[1]{\bgroup\ttfamily\ustextttaux#1\relax\relax}
\def\ustextttaux#1#2\relax{\ifx_#1\_\else#1\fi
  \allowbreak
  \ifx\relax#2\relax\def\next{\egroup}\else\def\next{\ustextttaux#2\relax}\fi
  \next}
\begin{document}
Here is an example
\ustexttt{multiple_words_long_with_underscores_representing_spaces}
of converted underscores, with autobreak enabled.
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you only want linebreaking following underscores, you can move the `\allowbreak` inside the prior `\ifx` block, following the `\_`.