# Adding font size to already defined command

Tags: beamer, equations, code

I am  using the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/232183/194846) to add source code to my beamer (usually inline), as:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95}
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\colorbox{light-gray}{\texttt{#1}}}
```

But then some lines of code cannot fit to a single line, so I have to reduce the font size to fit.

[image]

Then I add a font size to the `\code`  command like:

```
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\colorbox{light-gray}{\texttt{#1}[10pt]{\fontsize{#2}{#1}\selectfont #3}}}
```

This doesn't work. What's the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might change the definition into

```
\newcommand{\code}[2][]{\colorbox{light-gray}{\texttt{#1#2}}}
```

so you can call

```
\code{Some code to typeset}
```

or

```
\code[\tiny]{Some code to typeset}
```

Any font size changing command can be used as the optional argument. Even `\fontsize{2}{0}\selectfont` if you really want to make the slide unreadable. `;-)`